# Filter array to match other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, twitter, filter

I need to be able to filter an array based on ids contained in another array. Basically, I have an array of the tweet ids that contain a specific hashtag within the hashtag object I manipulate. `h.tweet_ids = [*someTweetID*, *someOtherTweetID*, …]`

On the other hand, I have the userTimeline array that contains all the tweets sent by the authenticating user.

Its structure looks like so (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline):

```
[
  {
    "coordinates": null,
    "favorited": false,
    "truncated": false,
    "created_at": "Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012",
    "id_str": "240859602684612608",
    "entities": {
      …
    },
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "text": "Introducing the Twitter Certified Products Program: https://t.co/MjJ8xAnT",
    "retweet_count": 121,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "id": 240859602684612608,
    "geo": null,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "place": null,
    "user": {
      …
    },
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "source": "<a href="//sites.google.com/site/yorufukurou/\"" rel="\"nofollow\"">YoruFukurou</a>",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null
  },
  {
    "coordinates": null,
    "favorited": false,
    "truncated": false,
    "created_at": "Sat Aug 25 17:26:51 +0000 2012",
    "id_str": "239413543487819778",
    "entities": {
      …
    },
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "text": "We are working to resolve issues with application management & logging in to the dev portal: https://t.co/p5bOzH0k ^TS",
    "retweet_count": 105,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "id": 239413543487819778,
    "geo": null,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "place": null,
    "user": {
      …
    },
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "source": "<a href="//sites.google.com/site/yorufukurou/\"" rel="\"nofollow\"">YoruFukurou</a>",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null
  }
]
```

What I would like to achieve is to filter the userTimeline to retrieve only the tweets whose ids (ie. `userTimleine[i].id_str`) are the ones in `h.tweet_ids`.

For the moment, I tried a loop inside a loop, but somehow it sometimes fails a goes into an infinite loop...

```
$scope.showTweetsForHashtag = function(h){
  var userTimeline = $scope.userTimeline,
     tweetId=h.tweetId,
     hTweets = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tweetId.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < userTimeline.length; j++) {
        if (userTimeline[j].id_str===tweetId[i]) {
           hTweets.push(userTimeline[j]);
        }
     }
  }
  $scope.selHash=h.Hashtag;
  $scope.hTweets=hTweets;
  if (!$scope.hModal) {
     $scope.hModal=true
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Cheers
^Q

Comment: What is the structure of `userTimeline` array?

Comment: Have a look at : https://lodash.com/docs#intersection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Thom-x, but I'm assuming that since I want to filter depending on an attribute value from userTimeline (ie. `"id_str"`), this method won't work...

Comment: You can first use https://lodash.com/docs#pluck and apply the first.

Answer (score 0):

With lodash I would do something like :

```js
var users = [
  {
    "coordinates": null,
    "favorited": false,
    "truncated": false,
    "created_at": "Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012",
    "id_str": "240859602684612608",
    "entities": {
    },
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "text": "Introducing the Twitter Certified Products Program: https://t.co/MjJ8xAnT",
    "retweet_count": 121,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "id": 240859602684612608,
    "geo": null,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "place": null,
    "user": {
    },
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "source": "",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null
  },
  {
    "coordinates": null,
    "favorited": false,
    "truncated": false,
    "created_at": "Sat Aug 25 17:26:51 +0000 2012",
    "id_str": "239413543487819778",
    "entities": {
    },
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "text": "We are working to resolve issues with application management & logging in to the dev portal: https://t.co/p5bOzH0k ^TS",
    "retweet_count": 105,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "id": 239413543487819778,
    "geo": null,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "place": null,
    "user": {
    },
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "source": "",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null
  }
];

var tweet_ids = ["240859602684612608", "000000"];
var matchIds = _.intersection(_.pluck(users, 'id_str'),tweet_ids );
var matchTweets = _.filter(users,function(userTmp){
  return matchIds.indexOf(userTmp.id_str) !== -1 ;
})

console.log(matchTweets);

$("body").append(JSON.stringify(matchTweets))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I would like to avoid using too many additional libraries... I was wondering if there was a way around with the array.filter() methods…

Comment: the `_.filter` can be replaced by `users.filter` but you'll have to code the `intersection` and `pluck` anyway :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way around without Lodash !

```
$scope.showTweetsForHashtag = function(h) {
    var userTimeline = $scope.userTimeline,
        tweetId = h.tweetId,
        hTweets = [];
    if (Array.isArray(tweetId)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tweetId.length; i++) {
            var hTweet = userTimeline.filter(function(el) {
                return el.id_str === tweetId[i];
            });
            hTweets = hTweets.concat(hTweet);
        }
        $scope.hTweets = hTweets;
    } else {
        $scope.hTweets = userTimeline.filter(function(el) {
            return el.id_str === tweetId;
        });
    }
    $scope.selHash = h.Hashtag;
    if (!$scope.hModal) {
        $scope.hModal = true
    }
};
```

Thanks anyway for your help !

^Q

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.filter` like http://jsfiddle.net/2LcpaeLm/:

```
var tweet_ids = [1,2,3,5,8,13,21];
var tweets = [{
    'id_str': 1
}, {
    'id_str': 4
}, {
    'id_str': 8
}, {
    'id_str': 11
}];

var filtered = tweets.filter(function (t) {
    for (var i = 0, len = tweet_ids.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (tweet_ids[i] == t.id_str)
            return true;
    }
});

console.log(filtered);
```